# service pptpd shows "is not running" but why it is still working?

Tags: services

In my ubuntu server 14.04, I start a pptpd service, when I check it status:

```
ubuntu@server:~$ service pptpd status
* /usr/sbin/pptpd is not running
```

But it actually is wokring:

```
ubuntu@server:~$ ps aux | grep pptpd
root      1053  0.0  0.0  10680   764 ?        Ss   Aug10   0:00 /usr/sbin/pptpd
```

Why this happens?

Comment: Try [Where to put “-p” for solving “pptpd is not running”?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/612462/where-to-put-p-for-solving-pptpd-is-not-running) first answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how the init detects the service is running (ie. with a file socket). If you run the process without this configuration, the init doesn't know of the actual state of the service.